# Multi Typed Data Class c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

My problem is as follows:

I need to create a class A that supports the following code:

```
class B{
   //some composed type
}

A a;
a.setValue(1);
a.setValue(2.2);
a.setValue('c');
a.setValue(B());
```

The catch is I need the a instance to keep the value that was set, and only it. Meaning I need a single variable that will contain the data, or that would point to the data, but the type is not known to A, and more types (such as B) could be added in the future.

Overloading doesn't solve this because where would the value be kept if the type is int as opposed to double?
Templates don't solve this, because the call to `a.setValue(...)` must look exactly like stated above, with no '<','>' characters that templates require.

I also tried implicit coercion by defining:

```
class MyObj{
   MyObj* theObj;
   MyObj(){}
   virtual ~MyObj() = 0;//with later empty implementation
   setValue(myObj* newVal){theObj = newVal;}
}
class MyInt:MyObj{
   myInt(){}
   myInt(int theInt){}//for implicit cast from int
}
a.setValue(1);
```

This fails because the compiler can auto convert int to myInt, but setValue expects myObj, so even though the coercion could work, the compiler doesn't make the deduction automatically.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Throwing [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html) out there.

Comment: `void*` or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html

Comment: The `var` class in JUCE could work too https://www.juce.com/api/classvar.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do, based on an ECS design pattern:

```
struct BaseType {
    virtual ~BaseType() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct SpecializedType : public BaseType{
    SpecializedType(const T& v) : val(v) {}
    ~SpecializedType() {}
    T val;
};

class A {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseType>> values;

public:
    template <typename T> void add(const T& val)
    {
        values.push_back(std::make_unique<SpecializedType<T>>(val));
    }

    template <typename T> T get()
    {
        for (auto& base : values)
        {
            auto* ptr = dynamic_cast<SpecializedType<T>*>(base.get());
            if (ptr)
                return ptr->val;
            }
            throw std::exception("no value found");
        }
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    A a;
    a.add(1.0f);
    a.add<std::string>("toto"); // You can specify the type when adding

    std::cout << a.get<float>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.get<std::string>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.get<int>() << std::endl; // Throws an exception because no int has been added
}
```

Pro:

- you can add every type you want
- C++11/14 memory managed

Cons:

- you can only have 1 value for each type
- dynamic_cast

Obviously you can improve the system if you want, i.e. by adding an identifier to the values to avoid the dynamic_cast